# Is there a specific name or descriptive term for happy, productive melodies/tunes that you see on ads?

Tags: terminology, melody

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDt1R8rb_D4)

Feel free to include some of your favorite ones also!

Comment: This is a word identification question, not a music theory or practice question. Please check out https://english.stackexchange.com/ for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you! What can I do to put this post in its proper community?

Comment: Go to the site that I linked and ask the question again there. There isn't a way for you to move this over to there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a word request better suited for English.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Commercial jingles?** I'm pretty sure that's the term in English... "Advertisement song" would be understood, but "Commercial Jingles" are a real phrase, I believe.